# Can't encode JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I created a JSON array in my PHP file as follows:

```
  $array[1] = "string1";
  $array[2] = "string2";
  $array[3] = "string3";   
  echo json_encode($array);
```

And I need to assign each string to different ID tags in my HTML.
This didn't work:

```
    success: function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('data');
    console.log(data);
    $("#id1").html(obj.1);
    $("#id2").html(obj.2);
    $("#id3").html(obj.3);
    }
```

And I am getting:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected number

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a string, right now you're encoding the string `data`, and that's all.

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // remove the quotes
    console.log(data);
    $("#id1").html(obj[1]);
    $("#id2").html(obj[2]);
    $("#id3").html(obj[3]);
}
```

Also, if you add the dataType JSON to the ajax call, the data will already be parsed.

Comment: And `obj[1]` instead of `obj.1` :)

Answer (score 0):

**data** is an **Object** you make it to an **String**

```
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```